# Given two sequences that have the same initial value, and both converge to zero, how do I prove that one is less or equal to the other?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions, derivatives, recursion

Given two sequences (perhaps are recursive functions instead) $a_n$ and $b_n$, defined on $N = [0,+\infty[$ which have the same initial term :

$a_0 = 0$

$b_0 = 0$

And are defined as follows :

$a_n = \frac {k - a_{n-1}} {c} + a_{n-1}$

$b_n = \frac {k - b_{n-1}} {d} + b_{n-1}$

with $k > 0$

Both sequences are increasing and converge to the value of $k$.

Given that $c < d$ how do I prove that $a_n \geq b_n$? or at least prove that the statement is correct for a given subset of $N$?

Knowing that $\frac {k - a_0} {c} > \frac {k - b_0} {d} $ from $c < d$, I could prove that $a_1 > b_1$. yet at one point, the condition $\frac {k - a_n} {c} > \frac {k - b_n} {d} $ will no longer hold since $a_n$ is converging faster to $k$ therefore at one point, the following will be true :

$\frac {k - a_n} {c} < \frac {k - b_n} {d} $

Trying it with concrete values always seems to verify that $a_n \geq b_n$ (in figures).

Any ideas on how to approach this problem? or atleast on how to define the ranges in which  $a_n \geq b_n$ is applicable?

Thank you in advance !

for $a_n, k=10, c=2$
[[image: for <span class=]$k=10, c=2$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F937T.png)

for $b_n, k=10, d=7$
[[image: for <span class=]$k=10, d=2$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORxXu.png)

generated through http://www.calcul.com/show/calculator/recursive

Comment: It is an easy exercice of induction. Under the conditions you stated $a_1 > b_1$ and for every $n>1$ we have $(a_{n}>b_{n}) \rightarrow (a_{n+1}>b_{n+1})$.

Comment: yes, but the problem is that $(a_n > b_n) \rightarrow  (k - a_n < k - b_n)$ which doesn't gurantee that $(a_{n+1} > b_{n+1})$ (since the derivative of $b_n$ is higher).

Comment: $$a_{n+1}-b_{n+1} = \frac{k}{c}-\frac{k}{d} + a_n(1-\frac{1}{c}) - b_n(1-\frac{1}{d}) > k(\frac{1}{c}-\frac{1}{d}) + (a_n - b_n)(1-(1/c))$$ then because $(k/c)-(k/d)>0$ and $a_n-b_n>0$, we obtain that $a_{n+1}-b_{n+1}>0$

Comment: Thank you, that would mean that $(1- \frac{1} {c}) > (1 - \frac{1} {d})$ which means that $a_n > b_n$ if $a_1 > b_1$. Thank you again !

Comment: $c < d \Rightarrow 1/c > 1/d \Rightarrow 1-(1/c) < 1-(1/d)$

Comment: I think you should add the assumption,$c\ge 1.$ Have you considered solving for $a_n$ and $b_n$ ? The recurrence relationship  are of the form $x_{n+1}=u+vx_n.$